# DAX: How to Calculate Max Date on Slicer Ignoring Year Selection

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm having trouble understanding why my DAX measure isn't working the way I expect it to.

At my company, we use an October 1-September 30 fiscal year. In Power BI, I have a date table called `'Posting Dates'` with a `Date` column and a `FY` column. My report has a date slicer, so the user can choose the maximum date. There is also a matrix visual with `FY` running across the columns.

I want to create a measure that captures the maximum date on the slicer ignoring any column selections. Here's the DAX I wrote:

```
Max Date on Slicer = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('Posting Dates'[Date]),
       REMOVEFILTER('Posting Dates', 'Posting Dates'[FY])
    )
```

I would expect the measure to remove all filters on the `'Posting Dates'` table except the `'Posting Dates'[Date]` filter. However, this does not seem to be what happens:
[image]

As you can see, the measure is returning the maximum date withing the fiscal year. I have also tried the following DAX with no luck:

```
Max Date on Slicer = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('Posting Dates'[Date]),
        AllEXCEPT('Posting Dates', 'Posting Dates'[Date])
    )
```

I know I can get the desired effect by messing with edit interactions, but I prefer to do this with DAX.

Comment: Do you have a sample .pbix you can share?